# How to prove $\sup{|x_{n}-y_{n}|} \le \sup{|x_{n} - z_{n}|} + \sup{|z_{n} - y_{n}|}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have 3 sequences with real entries: {$x_{n}$}, {$y_{n}$}, {$z_{n}$}.

I need to prove this:

$\sup{|x_{n}-y_{n}|} \le \sup{|x_{n} - z_{n}|} + \sup{|z_{n} - y_{n}|}$.

I prove it in the following way:

$|x_{n}-y_{n}| \le |x_{n} - z_{n}| + |z_{n} - y_{n}|$ is just consequence of the triangle inequality, since:

$|(x - z)-(z - y)| \le |x - z| + |z - y|$ and so

$|x - y| \le |x - z| + |z - y|$.

So I proved that this inequality holds for each element of these sequences with index n, i.e. $|x_{n}-y_{n}| \le |x_{n} - z_{n}| + |z_{n} - y_{n}|$.

Now I need to go from here to claiming that  $\sup{|x_{n}-y_{n}|} \le \sup{|x_{n} - z_{n}|} + \sup{|z_{n} - y_{n}|}$ .

Denote ${|x_{n}-y_{n}|}$ as {$a_{n}$}, ${|x_{n} - z_{n}|}$ as {$b_{n}$}, ${|z_{n} - y_{n}|}$ as {$c_{n}$}. Need: if $\forall n$ $\{a_{n}\} \le \{b_{n}\} + \{c_{n}\}$, then $\sup \{a_{n}\} \le \sup \{b_{n}\} + \sup \{c_{n}\}$.

In case of just sets A, B, C with $a \in A$, $b \in B$, $c \in C$ it is trivial:
if $a \le b + c$, then $a \le b + c \le \beta + \gamma$, where $\beta = \sup B$ and $\gamma = \sup C$. Thus $\sup A \le \sup B + \sup C$.

But how to proceed in the case of sequences {$a_{n}$}, {$b_{n}$}, {$c_{n}$}? Will exactly the same argument work?

Comment: |xn−yn|≤|xn−zn|+|zn−yn| . Thus sup LHS <= sup RHS. But sup RHS is less than the sum of the supremums of its summands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the same argument works. The $sup$ does not care about the order in the sequence. It is actually considering $sup$ of a set